# Unlocking file with CACLS command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cacls

The temptation was too great I had to test if for my self,

I’m talking about the `CACLS` command I used the following to lock a file from everything

```
CACLS C:\test.txt /p :n
```

Nice though I did this with the impression that:

```
CACLS C:\test.txt /p :f would also unlock this
```

Which fails even though the CMD keeps telling me the change was successful

How do I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the file from an explorer window. 
properties -> security -> add permission for your user (full control) and then delete the file :)